# Setting culture for date format in label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, internationalization, uiculture

How to set the culture correctly so that the Label's content is "seg" (Monday in Brazilian Portuguese)?

Setting ConverterCulture for the TextBlock Text binding changes it to pt-BR, but setting ConverterCulture for the Label's Content Binding does not. XAML below.

```
<Window x:Class="CurrentCulture.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <sys:DateTime x:Key="Td:Mon">2007-1-1</sys:DateTime>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Td:Mon}, ConverterCulture=pt-BR}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:ddd}"  />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Td:Mon}, ConverterCulture=pt-BR,StringFormat={}{0:ddd}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Text` property of TextBlock has type `string`, so the converter is used to convert DateTime to string applying the Brasilian style.

The `Content` property of the Label has type `object`. As DateTime is an object, no converter is used and so your ConverterCulture is ignored. The transforming to String is made by ContentStringFormat using the default language.

To get your desired result you can add an `Language="pt-BR"` attribute to your Label.